# C#, XAML, Metro - How to make some word bigger than others in the same textblock/textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to make a metro style news app and i want to make the first couple word in the news content bigger than the rest...
Please...is there anyway to do that...?
I'm thanking you in advance =]

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I was trying to use webview before...and it worked
but then I couldn't change the background image of the webview to transparent since I already have another background img in my app...
Now I just have to find another option T^T

Comment: Gotcha.  I think Reed's solution below should work just fine for you then.

Comment: Thanks to you by the way =]

Answer (score 5):

You can do this for `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Inlines>
     <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="Big and bold text " />
     <Run FontSize="10" Foreground="Red" Text="next to small red text. " />
  </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

However, `TextBox` doesn't support inlines, only a single text value, so this is not supported within a `TextBox`.